# OneNote Save Location

Tags: directory, onenote

I'm using OneNote 2013 on a Windows 7 64bit box.

I use OneNote and have two (2) separate notebooks, one for each of the projects I'm associated with. When I created the notebooks, I specified their locations (in a particular location which is automatically backed up to OneDrive). When I look at the properties for either of those notebooks, the Location is shown as that location I specified.

However, when I go to those two locations, in one of the directories there is a single .ms-one-stub file; in the other directory there is nothing at all.

Meanwhile, when I go the 'Save & Backup' options, it shows:

- Quick Notes Section: *c:\users\me\Documents\OneNote Notebooks\My Notebook\Quick Notes.one*
- Backup Folder: *c:\users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote*
- Default Notebook Location: *c:\users\me\Documents\OneNote Notebooks*

When I go to *c:\users\me\Documents\OneNote Notebooks\My Notebook*, there is a folder there named for one (and only one) of my two notebooks, and in that folder is the file *New Section 1.one* and *Open Notebook.onetoc2*.

I'm obviously not understanding how/where OneNote saves its data. How do I get it to actually save in the location I specify, and get the stuff out of *c:\user\me\Documents\OneNote* Notebooks?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using the paid version or the free version? There is no way to store files locally with the free version. That is because its all cloud based.

Comment: The paid version. We have the full O365 suite.

Comment: [check this link out, it might help you](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/how-do-i-use-onenote-with-a-local-account-i-dont/2a8431dd-228e-4a8e-bc16-214fb6056bc1?auth=1)

Comment: It sort of did. But I must confess I'm still a little confused. I have the paid version, with O365. So OneNote does not actually save to the hard disk, like Word and Excel (even with O365)? That's what I really want - a single save file that I can have in a known particular location, ensuring that that location is one that is automatically backed up to OneDrive (simply by being in a folder that is configured to do so).

Comment: are you doing notebooks creation pro-grammatically?